# How to get a report Id in LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I need to navigate to a specific report in LWC. How to get the report id instead of hardcoding it?

```
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: '00O0M000000kjL1UBU',
            objectApiName: 'Report',
            actionName: 'view'
        }
        
    });
```

Comment: More context is required. Is it one report, always? Dynamic report? Different report per user? How are you defining which report it is?

Comment: @DavidReed it is one Report always. wont be changed dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the report Id using "wire" method in LWC by passing Name filter in SOQL query.
Below is the code example:

Apex:

```
public class FetchReports{

  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static String getReportId(String reportName){
   return [SELECT Id,Name FROM Report WHERE Name=:reportName LIMIT 1]?.Id;
  }
}
```

LWC .JS File:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getReportId from '@salesforce/apex/FetchReports.getReportId';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class Gettersetter extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){
   reportId;
   error;

   @wire(getReportId,{reportName:'yourReportName'})
   report({data,error}){
     if(data){
       this.reportId=data;
     }
     else if(error){
     this.error=error;
     }
  }

   navigatetoReport(event){
      this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
          type: 'standard__recordPage',
          attributes: {
            recordId: this.reportId,
            objectApiName: 'Report',
            actionName: 'view'
          }
    });
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you!